# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error shows when adding a reference to a WCF service to a Silverlight 4 project

Tags: silverlight, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have a Silverlight enabled WCF service, and a Silverlight 4 project that references it.

The service used to work nicely until I merged some changes another developer made into the service, since then the Silverlight project failed to call the service with "Server not found" error.

I removed the reference to the service, tried to add it again but this failed with error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

This is not limited to the above service anymore, this error happens every time I try to add any WCF service to the Silverlight project.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and the .NET Framework 4.0 for all projects. 
This problem has happened before and I was able to solve it be creating a new solution, creating fresh projects in it and then adding the code files to the projects one by one. However, this is a nightmare now that my solution contains dozens of projects and hundreds of code files.

anyone out there with a fix for this? I googled this a dozen times and all I got was fixes to similar problems that happened with Silverlight 2 and Visual Studio 2008, but these fixes didn't work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your WCF service is working properly. Right click on the SVC file and select View in browser. If there is a runtime problem, that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: The WCF service is working properly, and I can reference it successfully from any Silverlight project other than the one mentioned in the question.

Comment: Try checking your project assembly references and make sure they didn't get hosed somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching WCF tracing on?  I find it normally provides clues to the problem source.  Also, have you checked your Silverlight client config?  Are the end point addresses all correct?

Comment: The WCF service is working properly, and I can reference it successfully from any Silverlight project other than the one mentioned in the question.